# Access (possible VBA) Export to multiple files based on column content

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I currently have a dataset that contains information for arrivals at over 100 airports. My end goal is create an excel file with a tab for each of those airports containing only the information for that airport (multiple rows).

I can of course create 100 queries and export them in a macro. However the list may change overtime and while I can amend the query that creates the initial file I'd rather not have to tweak the downstream process each time.

I cannot amend the source file process so do not want to export 105 initial files each time.

I am looking for a process that will export based on the contents of the data.

Comment: Hi. I am in the stage of conceptualising this solution and my VBA is limited but I figured it would be possible. Essentially I am looking for guidance to avoid 100 queries and to increase my VBA skills or my approach.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is pretty general, here's a general approach I might take.

1. Query the data to get a distinct list of airports.
2. Loop over list from #1, building a set of data just for that airport.
3. Export the data from #2 to Excel.

The details on how to do each of those is going to depend on what the initial dataset looks like and is beyond the scope of what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that a process to loop through that distinct list is only achievable from writing VBA rather than anything else built in to Access. I can supply more information but am unsure what you would want to make it less general. Thanks.

Comment: There probably is some way to do this using a set of queries, but I would use VBA for this, yes.